# Erro de sintaxe UPDATE no delphi (MySQL)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Boa noite.... estou usando um procedimento no msm estilo para todos os modulos do meu software usando a msm estrutura de UPDATE e em todos funcionaram, porem quando fui fazer o update de usuarios do sistema esta me retornando o erro : sintaxe do comando UPDATE incorreta... vou deixar o codigo a baixo alguem por favor sabeo que está acontecendo?
obrigado

```
    procedure TModulo.EditarUsuario(idPr: Integer; userPr: string; senhaPr:        string);
    begin

   with reserva do begin

       Close;
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('UPDATE usuarios SET user = :userPr, senha = :senhaPr ' +
    'where id = ' + IntToStr(idPr));

        Parameters.ParamByName('userPr').Value := userPr;
        Parameters.ParamByName('senhaPr').Value := senhaPr;

        ExecSQL;

    end;

      //resetando para visualização
      DMDados.Modulo.reserva.close;
      DMDados.Modulo.reserva.sql.Clear;
      DMDados.Modulo.reserva.sql.Add('select * from usuarios');
      DMDados.Modulo.reserva.open;
      //resetando para visualização</>

    end;
```

Comment: Posta o erro que tá dando junto

Comment: Erro na SINTAXED da instrução UPDATE só isso

Comment: Creio que esteja faltando colocar o usuário e senha entre aspas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que eu pude observar, só falou especificar o ID no ParamByName

```
reserva.Close;
reserva.SQL.Clear;
reserva.SQL.Add('UPDATE USUARIOS SET');
reserva.SQL.Add('USER = :USERPR,');
reserva.SQL.Add('SENHA = :SENHAPR');
reserva.SQL.Add('WHERE ID = :IDPR');

reserva.ParamByName('IDPR').AsInteger := idPr;
reserva.ParamByName('USERPR').AsString := userPr;
reserva.ParamByName('SENHAPR').AsString := senhaPr;
reserva.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Cara tentei aqui mas n achou a funcao asstring

Comment: Tens que declarar no uses Data.DB

Comment: vixi esse erro ta cabuloso tb n foi kk engraçado que nos outros modulos usei a mesma estrutura no update e foi normal so nessa tabela que ta dando ruim

Comment: tem como fazer um backup dessa tabela e criar novamente

Comment: beleza vou tentar recriala depois

Comment: Três coisas... 1.) Antes do comando `ExecSql` execute o comando `SQL.SaveToFile('arquivo.txt')` e nos mande o resultado. 2.) Como está estruturada a tabela? E 3.) Debugando o código, como estão preenchidas as variáveis **idPr**, **userPr** e **senhaPr**?